# Android: Trouble removing a Layout set using setContentView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

As title suggests, I have trouble clearing/removing/killing the Layout I set using the setContentView. The problem is seen when I press back button on the screen.

Details -

From parent layout `xyz_parent_layout`, I call a method `showMeTheImage()` which loads the image preview by calling `setContentView(yzx_image_layout)`. Now to go back to `xyz_parent_layout`, press on the back button which calls `parent.removeView(imageview)` but nothing happens. I have also used `((ViewManager)imageview.getParent()).removeView(imageview)`, this clears the imagepreview but presents a blank screen after that.

Another problem is that by pressing back hard key on the imagepreview screen is actually handled on parent screen.

I also want to understand how to handle Back hard key press on imageView screen.

Not sure what is happening, any help is really appreciated.

Update - with code

```
parent = (LinearLayout)mInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent, null);
button = (Button)parent.findViewById(R.id.button_dosomething);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View buttonView)
    {
        showImageView();
    }
});

context.setContentView(parent);

showImageView()
{   
    imagePreview = (RelativeLayout)mInflater.inflate(com.xxx.R.layout.yzx_image_layout,null);
    Button back = (Button)imagePreview.findViewById(com.xxx.R.id.back_button);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View backButton)
                    {
                        //Do something

                    }
                });         
    parent.addView(imagePreview);           
    context.setContentView(parent);         
}
```

Thanks,
SKU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking of this wrong. When you call `setContentView()` the second time, it is not setting that `layout` as a child of `xyz_parent_layout.xml`. It is setting the content for the whole screen as `yzx_image_layout`.

What it sounds like you want to do is to inflate `yzx_image_layout.xml` and add it to your `xyz_parent_layout` in the `showMeTheImage()` function. Then when you call `removeView()` on your parent `layout` it will remove that child.

I don't know exactly what you are doing but another option, posssibly easier, is to put your image layout in a separate `Activity` then in your function you start that `Activity`. This way, when you press the back button it will remove that `Activity` from the stack and return to your first `Activity` where you have your `xyz_parent_layout`.

It doesn't sound like you want that to be a full-screen `Activity` so you can add the following line to the appropriate `<activity>` tag in your `manifest.xml`

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

to give it a `Dialog` appearance.

**Edit**

```
setContentView(R.layout.parent);   // assuming you have a layout file named parent.xml
parent = (LinearLayout)mInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent, null);
button = (Button)parent.findViewById(R.id.button_dosomething);
startOdometerPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View buttonView)
    {
        showImageView();
    }
 });
```

And remove

```
context.setContentView(parent);
```

from your `showImage()` function.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, but to make sure - what you are suggesting is that do parent.addView(imageView) and then use parent.removeView(imageview) to clear it. Using another Activity is something I don't have luxury of using in this project.

Comment: Yes, but make sure that `imageView` doesn't have a parent `layout`. If so you will have to remove it from its current parent first before adding it to the new one

Comment: Hi codeMagic, really appreciate your help and follow up. I tried following thing after your 1st suggestion - I inflated the parent layout and then inflated the imageview layout, later added it to the parent and then setContentView(parent). But this drew a blank page.

Comment: Call `setContentView()` **then** inflate your second `layout` and add it to the `layout` you inflated in `setContentView()`. calling `setContentView()` is a way of `inflating` the `layout`. When you call it last it just sets the `layout` to whatever is in that method and the `layout` stuff you did prior doesn't matter anymore

Comment: codeMagic, I am not sure I understand your previous statement. I have updated the question with latest changes as per your 1st comment. Can you please take a look and suggest accordingly. Thanks a Lot

Comment: Bingo... It worked. Thanks a lot. Just another question - Do you think its good idea to use parent.removeAllViews() before we add the imageView to parent or change the visibility of the parent Layout. This will help me to get the image view full screen and handling the back button effectively. What do you suggest?

Comment: `removeAllViews()` should be fine